# find -print0 recursive

Tags: bash, find

I need to list all files in a directory and their subdirectories, save them in an array and do some stuffs (basically for-loop the array and set attributes)

I started with:

```
var=$(find ./ -type f)
```

My problem here is that file names contain spaces and other unfriendly characters (not my bad!) and this makes quiet complicated parsing the array of strings (namely the output of find command.

So I found I can use *find -print0* which works great except for the fact it does not looks recursively (only directory, not subdirectory).

Is there a parameter I can pass to look recursively or equivalently a command which

- list all files in dir and subdir
- save the list as array of strings?

Comment: `find` _is_ recursive. If you think it isn't, you could show a concrete example, and perhaps someone could tell what's wrong with it. (Dealing with the NUL-separated filenanes is another issue.)

Comment: @ilkkachu I do not exclude I may have used terms not so accurate. Suppose your current directory has 2 folders, each folder has some files, type "find ./ -print0". This will print just what inside your current directory (so folder1 and folder2) and not what inside those directories. This is what I meant with "recursive"

Comment: @ilkkachu sorry, my mistake, I use softlink and I used find without "-L" flag

Comment: If you want to process a set of files you can have `find` manage that for you without needing to save the list of files and then loop over them. Tell us the sort of thing you want to achieve and we can help you with a more direct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake, I am using softlink and I did not use *find* with *-L* flag.

```
original_list=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'; do
    original_list+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find -L ./ -type f -print0)
```

This works!

Comment: Does this work? I think you're missing `REPLY` as a name in `read`'s arguments.

Comment: @Torin yes, it does. If you don't assign a variable to `read` then the value will be assigned by default to `REPLY` variable. See `man bash` and search `REPLY`. (also works in zsh)

Answer (score 3):

`find` is always recursive¹, but your:

> ```
> var=$(find ./ -type f)
> ```

is a *scalar* variable assignment, not an array variable assignment. `$var` ends up containing one string: the full output of `find` including the newline characters²

An array variable assignment in bash, which copied the zsh syntax is with:

```
var=( 'first element' second-element etc... )
```

To get each file as output by `find -print0`, you'd need to split the output of `find` on NUL characters though. In zsh, you'd use the `0` parameter expansion flag for that³:

```
var=( ${(0)"$(find . -type f -print0)"} )
```

Bash has no equivalent and in general can't store NULs in its data structures. However, since version 4.4, you can use its `readarray` builtin in combination with process substitution:

```
readarray -td '' var < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

`readarray` stores each record from its input (here a pipe from `find` created via process substitution) as separate elements. With `-d ''`, the record separator is NUL instead of newline. With `-t`, the record delimiter is removed. It's not needed in current versions of bash as bash can't store NULs in its variables anyway, but we're adding it for future-proofing.

To loop over the elements, you'd do:

```
for file in "${var[@]}"; do
  something with "$file"
done
```

Here, you could also do without the array and loop directly over the output of `find` with:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' -u3 file; do
  something with "$file"
done 3< <(find . -type f -print0)
```

See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) for how to properly loop over the files found by `find` in general.

---

<sup>¹ unless you tell it explicitly not to descend into some directories with `-prune` or `-xdev`, or with some `find` implementation limit the depth with `-maxdepth`. It will however not follow symlinks to directories unless you use the `-L` option or `-follow` predicate<sup>4</sup></sup>

<sup>² except the trailing ones which are stripped by the command subsitution.</sup>

<sup>³ well, in `zsh`, you wouldn't need `find` and that non-standard `-print0` in the first place, you'd just use its recursive globs and glob qualifiers: `var=( **/*(ND.) )` or `var=( ***/*(ND.) )` to follow symlinks.</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup> Beware however that `-L`/`-follow` also has an influence on the behaviour `-type`. Here `-type f` would end up also selecting symlinks to regular files. With the GNU implementation of `find`, you can use `-xtype f` with `-L` to only select  regular files and not symlink to regular files like `-type f` does without `-L`</sup>